# How can i update my chatbot with chatgpt from "text-davinci-003" to "gpt-3.5-turbo" in python

Tags: python, chatbot, whatsapp, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I'm new in python and i want a little hand into this code.
I'm developing a smart chatbot using the openai API and using it in what's app. I have this piece of my code that is responsible for the **chatgpt response** in my code. At the moment, this code is on model = "text-davinci-003" and i want to turn it into "gpt-3.5-turbo". Is any good soul interested in helping me?

Obs.: "msg" is what we ask to `chatgpt` on whatsapp

The piece of my code:

```
msg = todas_as_msg_texto[-1]
print(msg) # -> Mensagem que o cliente manda (no caso eu)

cliente = 'msg do cliente: '
texto2 = 'Responda a mensagem do cliente com base no próximo texto: '
questao = cliente + msg + texto2 + texto

# #### PROCESSA A MENSAGEM NA API DO CHAT GPT ####

openai.api_key= apiopenai.strip()

response=openai.Completion.create(
    model="text-davinci-003",
    prompt=questao,
    temperature=0.1,
    max_tokens=270,
    top_p=1,
    frequency_penalty=0,
    presence_penalty=0.6,
)

resposta=response['choices'][0]['text']
print(resposta)
time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update your code to `gpt-3.5-turbo`, there are four areas you need to modify:

1. Call `openai.ChatCompletion.create` instead of `openai.Completion.create`
2. Set `model='gpt-3.5-turbo'`
3. Change `messages=` to an array as shown below
4. Change the way you are assigning `repsonse` to your `resposta` variable so that you are reading from the `messages` key

This tested example takes into account those changes:

```python
response=openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages=[{"role": "user", "content": questao }],
    temperature=0.1,
    max_tokens=270,
    top_p=1,
    frequency_penalty=0,
    presence_penalty=0.6,
)

resposta=response['choices'][0]['message']['content']
```

Additionally, since more than one choice can be returned from the model, instead of only looking at `[0]` you may be interested in iterating over them to see what you're getting, something like:

```python
for choice in response.choices:
            outputText = choice.message.content
            print(outputText)
            print("------")
print("\n")
```

Note that you don't need to do that if you are calling `openai.ChatCompletion.create` with 'n=1'

Additionally, your example is setting both `temperature` and `top_p`, however the [docs suggest to only set one of those variables](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create#chat/create-temperature).

Comment: Hi Derek! Thanks for the help. There is only another thing that i want to know. Instead of passing "questão" on messages field, before, I want to pass something to the prompt for example: "You are going to be a  medical secretary...." and create a loop of a conversation based on previous questions and answers. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, busse. I'm new here...

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
import requests
import json
# Create HTTP client and request objects
httpClient1 = requests.Session()
url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions"
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + OpenaiApiKey}
prompt = "Hello, how are you?"
request1 = {
"model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
"messages": [{"role": "user", "content": prompt}]
}
# Send the request and wait for the response
response1 = httpClient1.post(url, headers=headers, json=request1)
responseContent1 = response1.content
# Deserialize the JSON response and extract the generated text
responseObject1 = json.loads(responseContent1.decode('utf-8'))
results = responseObject1["choices"][0]["text"]
```