# Python OpenAI API error: module 'openai' has no attribute 'Completion'. Did you mean: 'completions'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, openai-api, gpt-3

I try to make a bot for my website in Python. But I have an error.

**The Error:**

```
You: hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\module2.py", line 20, in <module>
    response = chat_with_gpt(user_input)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\module2.py", line 6, in chat_with_gpt
    response = openai.Completion.create(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'openai' has no attribute 'Completion'. Did you mean: 'completions'?
```

**This is the Python code:**

I tried many combinations, and I also tried with `text-davinci-003`, but nothing worked.

```
import openai

openai.api_key = "API-KEY"

def chat_with_gpt(prompt):
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        # engine="text-davinci-003",  # Adjust the engine as necessary
        engine="gpt-3.5-turbo",  # Adjust the engine as necessary
        prompt=prompt,
        max_tokens=150
    )
    return response.choices[0].text.strip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        user_input = input("You: ")
        user_input = user_input.lower()
        if user_input in ["quit", "exit", "bye"]:
            break
        response = chat_with_gpt(user_input)
        print("Chatbot:", response)
```

Comment: Why do you think that `openai` should have an attribute called `Completion`?

Comment: And did you make sure that it shouldn't have been `completions` as suggested by the error message ?

Comment: I made my code, buy the code here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76040193/how-can-i-update-my-chatbot-with-chatgpt-from-text-davinci-003-to-gpt-3-5-tur

Comment: I change it with:  `response = openai.completions.create(` and I get the error: `
  File "C:\Users\necul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openai\_utils\_utils.py", line 298, in wrapper
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: Missing required arguments; Expected either ('model' and 'prompt') or ('model', 'prompt' and 'stream') arguments to be given
>>> `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code:

- using the wrong method name (i.e., `Completion`)
- using the deprecated parameter (i.e., `engine`)
- using the incompatible model with the [Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/text-generation/completions-api)

The following code should work:

```
response = openai.completions.create( # Changed
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct", # Changed
    prompt=prompt,
    max_tokens=150
)
```

Comment: yes, thanks, better. But also, I get this error: `  File "C:\Users\necul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 877, in _request
    raise self._make_status_error_from_response(err.response) from None
openai.RateLimitError: Error code: 429 - {'error': {'message': 'You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details. For more information on this error, read the docs: https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/error-codes/api-errors.', 'type': 'insufficient_quota', 'param': None, 'code': 'insufficient_quota'}}`

Comment: See [OpenAI API error 429: "You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75898276/openai-api-error-429-you-exceeded-your-current-quota-please-check-your-plan-a/75898717#75898717).

Comment: thanks. Indeed. Were very good you solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
from openai import OpenAI

client = OpenAI()

completion = client.chat.completions.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages=[
        {
            "role": "system",
            "content": "You are a poetic assistant, skilled in explaining complex programming concepts with creative flair.",
        },
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": "Compose a poem that explains the concept of recursion in programming.",
        },
    ],
)

print(completion.model_dump()['choices'][0]['message']['content'])
```

[Source](https://community.openai.com/t/attributeerror-module-openai-has-no-attribute-chatcompletion/81490/74)